# Grouping items in a listview when using Caliburn micro and MVVM

Tags: c#, listview, grouping, caliburn.micro

I'm completely new to MVVM.  I've googled the crap out of this ridiculous problem but can't find anything.

I have a Listview on my form that I populate with a DB call.  That's all fine, but I would like to group the items in the list view by a property called Status.

Ordinarily this would be no problem I would add a PropertyGroupDescription to the control after binding the data but the MVVM aspect of things is getting in the way.

When I set the data property in the view model, I can't set the PropertyGroupDescription on the control because I don't have access to it in the ViewModel.

I can't set it in the xaml codebehind because I can't get any events to fire when the data changes.

I know this is probably a ridiculously simple problem for those of you in the know, but I feel like I'm banging my head against a brick wall here, so much so I actually created a StackOverflow account :)

**viewModel Code**

```
    class SearchViewModel : Screen
    {
        private BindableCollection<Claim> _searchResults;
        private string _searchString;
            
        public string SearchString
        {
            get { return _searchString; }
            set { _searchString = value; }
        }

        public BindableCollection<Claim> SearchResults
        {
            get { return _searchResults; }
            set 
            {
                _searchResults = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SearchResults); 
            }
        }

        public async void DoSearch()
        {
            List<Claim> results = await AugmentorCore.Search.SearchTelephones(SearchString);
            SearchResults = new BindableCollection<Claim>(results);
        }

        public void SearchBoxKeyDown(ActionExecutionContext context)
        {
            KeyEventArgs keyArgs = context.EventArgs as KeyEventArgs;
            if (keyArgs.Key == Key.Enter)
                DoSearch();
        }
        public void SearchResultsUpdated(ActionExecutionContext context)
        {
            // Trying to get an event on the control to fire this.
            //ListView source = context.Source as ListView;
            //CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(source.ItemsSource);
            //PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("status");
            //view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
            MessageBox.Show("In SearchResultsUpdated");
        }
    }
```

**XAML (abbreviated)**

```
                <ListView
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                    x:Name="SearchResults">
                    
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn 
                                Header="Case/Name"
                                Width="150" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding reference}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                    
                                        
                    <ListView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </ListView.GroupStyle>
                </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I have understood your issue correctly. You could do the following.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.DataContext>
                <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding SearchResults}" >
                    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Status" />
                    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                </CollectionViewSource>
            </ListBox.DataContext>

....
...
</ListView>
```

Comment: Oh my god that totally works!  Thank you so much!  I don't suppose you know where I could find documentation on that solution so I've got a better idea of how to solve it myself in the future do you?